# Git: Setting up public, read-only clone on local network

Tags: git, local, filesystem-access

We have a small Windows LAN with a bare repository origin for research data set up on a network drive and a working clone on each workstation; all is well.  We'd like to provide read-only access to the repository for visitors (the actual physical kind) who connect.  What's the best way?

Logically (= naively) we'd make it a non-bare origin and just expose that with no external write permissions; I tried that when setting it up but pushing to a full origin wasn't nice.  Should I make a public clone right next to the origin, and make that read-only?  And then: what kind of hooks to use to make that public clone get updated whenever a worker pushes?

Pretty much all info I find about this is about *nix systems and remote access, which sadly are not the case here.

Comment: You could add your repository to something like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview) to handle this. You can set up "groups", for example all of the people in your department as "devleopers". So then you can give that group read/write access to the repo, then by default everyone else only gets read access. See [more about permissions here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-privacy-permissions-and-more-221449716.html)

Comment: @CoryKramer Right, we've thought about that kind of thing and want to do it, but for now institutional oppressions discourage out-of-network experiences like that.  Maybe later we can.

Comment: It doesn't have to be out-of-network. You can set up a Bitbucket server locally that is not visible outside your network. You needn't host the code out on some other remote site.

Comment: Ohh... I see!  Well pardon my ignorance and bless your eyes; I'll have to dig in to that.  Still, I'm interested in the vanillagit answer, just to understand.

Comment: The vanilla git way to do something like this is to use [group permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine). Easier on linux (using e.g. `chmod`), but possible on windows too using group policies, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but permissions I understand (in principle).  What I don't get is the right place for the public copy.  The bare repository is no use to anyone, and I don't believe it'd be good to set up one of our working clones to also be publically readable, so... *is* the vanilla answer to set up a separate read-only clone next to the bare repository?  And what hooks for updating?  Just trying to get my basics down, and apologies for the drawn-out thread.